# Cannot download Pytorch

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, stable-diffusion

I have been trying to download Pytorch for use with Automatic1111 but am getting the error below. This error also occurs when trying to install pytorch via the commandline using

```
python -m pip --default-timeout=600 install torch==1.13.1+cu117 torchvision==0.14.1+cu117 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117 --no-cache-dir
```

The Python version I have is 3.10.6 and I have confirmed this using `py -0p`. I have tried

- updating the pip version
- downloading the pytorch wheel directly and installing it via pip install
- changing the python install folder to ProgramFiles instead of users folder

I would appreciate any help I can get. Please see the error below.

```
C:\Users\ofent_sft39e7>python -m pip --default-timeout=600 install torch==1.13.1+cu117 torchvision==0.14.1+cu117 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117 --no-cache-dir
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117
Collecting torch==1.13.1+cu117
  Downloading https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117/torch-1.13.1%2Bcu117-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (2255.4 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╺━━━ 2.0/2.3 GB 9.8 MB/s eta 0:00:22
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ofent_sft39e7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 438, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "C:\Users\ofent_sft39e7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 561, in read
    data = self._fp_read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
  File "C:\Users\ofent_sft39e7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 527, in _fp_read
    return self._fp.read(amt) if amt is not None else self._fp.read()
  File "C:\Users\ofent_sft39e7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 465, in read
    s = self.fp.read(amt)
  File "C:\Users\ofent_sft39e7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\socket.py", line 705, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Users\ofent_sft39e7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1274, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "C:\Users\ofent_sft39e7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1130, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
TimeoutError: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ofent_sft39e7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 180, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\ofent_sft39e7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 248, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "C:\Users\ofent_sft39e7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 377, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "C:\Users\ofent_sft39e7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 92, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "C:\Users\ofent_sft39e7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 546, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "C:\Users\ofent_sft39e7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 397, in resolve
    self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
  File "C:\Users\ofent_sft39e7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 173, in _add_to_criteria
    if not criterion.candidates:
  File "C:\Users\ofent_sft39e7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\structs.py", line 156, in __bool__
    return bool(self._sequence)
  File "C:\Users\ofent_sft39e7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 155, in __bool__
    return any(self)
  File "C:\Users\ofent_sft39e7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 143, in <genexpr>
    return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
  File "C:\Users\ofent_sft39e7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 47, in _iter_built
    candidate = func()
  File "C:\Users\ofent_sft39e7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\factory.py", line 206, in _make_candidate_from_link
    self._link_candidate_cache[link] = LinkCandidate(
  File "C:\Users\ofent_sft39e7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 293, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\ofent_sft39e7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.dist = self._prepare()
  File "C:\Users\ofent_sft39e7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 225, in _prepare
    dist = self._prepare_distribution()
  File "C:\Users\ofent_sft39e7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 304, in _prepare_distribution
    return preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(self._ireq, parallel_builds=True)
  File "C:\Users\ofent_sft39e7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 538, in prepare_linked_requirement
    return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
  File "C:\Users\ofent_sft39e7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 609, in _prepare_linked_requirement
    local_file = unpack_url(
  File "C:\Users\ofent_sft39e7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 166, in unpack_url
    file = get_http_url(
  File "C:\Users\ofent_sft39e7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 107, in get_http_url
    from_path, content_type = download(link, temp_dir.path)
  File "C:\Users\ofent_sft39e7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\download.py", line 147, in __call__
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "C:\Users\ofent_sft39e7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\progress_bars.py", line 53, in _rich_progress_bar
    for chunk in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\ofent_sft39e7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\utils.py", line 63, in response_chunks
    for chunk in response.raw.stream(
  File "C:\Users\ofent_sft39e7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 622, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "C:\Users\ofent_sft39e7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 560, in read
    with self._error_catcher():
  File "C:\Users\ofent_sft39e7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\contextlib.py", line 153, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\ofent_sft39e7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 443, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='download.pytorch.org', port=443): Read timed out.
```

Comment: 2.3GB is a very large download. 600 seconds may just not enough time.  Try 1200.

Comment: Tried that, just hung on 1.7GB this time and then timed out, really frustrating. I have a relatively fast internet so this confuses me

Comment: Are you behind a corporate firewall that might be interfering?